# How do I get a file size(original file size) within .tar.gz without uncompress it?

Tags: command-line, files, tar, gzip

I make myfile.txt to zip file with below command, is there a way to get original file size 'myfile.txt' without unzipping it.

```
tar -czf myfile.tar.gz myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the uncompressed size of a ZIP file we can issue [**gzip**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gzip) with option `--list` or `-l`

```
gzip -l mytext.txt.tar.gz
```

This will give an output similar to this

```
gzip -l mytext.txt.tar.gz
         compressed        uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
               1475                4608  68.4% mytext.txt.tar
```

To have the compressed file size, the uncompressed size, and the compression ratio.

Comment: If you are only interested in the uncompressed size of all files in a folder use: `for i in $DIR/*; do gzip --list $i; done|grep -v uncomp|cut -b 25-40| paste -s -d+ - | bc

`

Answer (score 4):

You can list the content (including original file sizes) of the tar file using:

```
tar -vtf myfile.tar.gz
```

If you only want `myfile.txt`:

```
tar -vtf myfile.tar.gz myfile.txt
```

This only works if you add the full file path, otherwise use:

```
tar -vtf myfile.tar.gz | grep myfile.txt
```

Note that tar will have to decompress the archive in order to get to the file information. It will however hide that from you.

If you specifically need a way to get to file meta-data without having to decompress the whole archive, you are better off using zip to store your files and directories. Zip uses a 'central directory' at the end of a zip-file that stores all file meta-data.

Comment: why don't we need the "z" in the command.  It used to be necessary to signal that the gz should be ungzipped.  "tar -tzvf fn.tar.gz", where t=test, z=unzip, v=verbose, f=filename.

Comment: This command actually uncompress the archive on the air.

Comment: @pauljohn32: tar is smart enough to detect the format, You only need it when creating an archive. See https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC136

Comment: @Ravexina: That is correct and it can't be done in any other way because the .tar file holds the file metadata.

Comment: @NZD , Yeah, However I think OP is looking for someway to do it without uncompressing the file ;)

Comment: @Ravexina: Thanks, update my answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding everything sites in the web, and don't resolve this problem the get size when file size is  bigger of 4GB.

first, which is most faster?

```
[oracle@base tmp]$ time zcat oracle.20180303.030001.dmp.tar.gz | wc -c
    6667028480

    real    0m45.761s
    user    0m43.203s
    sys     0m5.185s
```

```
[oracle@base tmp]$ time gzip -dc oracle.20180303.030001.dmp.tar.gz | wc -c
    6667028480

    real    0m45.335s
    user    0m42.781s
    sys     0m5.153s
```

```
[oracle@base tmp]$ time tar -tvf oracle.20180303.030001.dmp.tar.gz
    -rw-r--r-- oracle/oinstall 111828 2018-03-03 03:05 oracle.20180303.030001.log
    -rw-r----- oracle/oinstall 6666911744 2018-03-03 03:05 oracle.20180303.030001.dmp

    real    0m46.669s
    user    0m44.347s
    sys     0m4.981s
```

definitely, **tar -xvf** is the most faster, but
¿how to cancel executions after get header?

**my solution is this**:

```
[oracle@base tmp]$  time echo $(timeout --signal=SIGINT 1s tar -tvf oracle.20180303.030001.dmp.tar.gz | awk '{print $3}') | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }'
    6667023572

real    0m1.029s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.063s
```

Comment: @dsstorefile I forgot to put execution time in the last command, which shows the significant reduction. and you can see the cancellation of decompression with the "timeout" command